# How to deploy my web application on tc server?

Tags: spring-data, tcserver, spring-insight

I have a war file.

before deploying on tc server, I successfully deployed on tomcat :

1. Copy the war in webapps folder, copy mysql connector in libs folder.

2.Configure server.xml

Now on pivotal tc server developer edition 3.0.0, I have created an instance of type insight (for Spring Insight).

I have copied my war in webapps folder of that instance.
Copied mysql connector in libs folder,
Configured the server.xml

When I run the tc server instance, the war starts up normally  and then due to nested dependency exception, so many exceptions come and it all fails.

Some logs :

Log when the war is starting (trimmed) :

```
17:35:13.510 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19ed05c9:
```

After many such logs, there is a destroying singleton beans log (trimmed):

```
17:35:15.408 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19ed05c9:
```

After a big chunk of the above logs :

```
17:35:15.519 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
```

After this :

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SomeBean' defined in file.....(trimmed)... Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [packagename.someRepository: : Error creating bean with name 'someRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:738) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992) [catalina.jar:7.0.55.A]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490) [catalina.jar:7.0.55.A]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.55.A]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.55.A]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.55.A]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649) [catalina.jar:7.0.55.A]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083) [catalina.jar:7.0.55.A]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880) [catalina.jar:7.0.55.A]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
```

In logs you see, it is not able to create "someRepository", where someRepository is just a JPA Repository for a domain object, nothing complex.

Also nested exception this is also there:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback
```

Please let me know if any other information is required.

Thanks a lot in advance for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception suggests, you're missing the spring transaction module on the classpath (`org.springframework:spring-tx:…`).

Comment: Hi,
That's what I thought initially. I checked build.gradle, the dependency was there,
Also in the deployed war, libs directory, the spring-tx jar is present, still I am getting this error.